# What does 「他にやたら」mean in this sentence? 「今はいないけど他にやたら頑丈なお姉さんもいるんですよ」

Tags: meaning, words

I found this line while watching an anime and can't I don't know what word to look for in the dictionary for it

> 今はいないけど、他にやたら頑丈なお姉さんもいるんですよ

What does 「他にやたら」mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please always include as much context as you possibly can and make sure to include a source too if you can find it online. I did it for you. From [劇場版「紅伝説」](https://anime-kannsou.com/archives/1373)

> ふにふら「本当に実在したのね。ゆんゆんのパーティー仲間」
>
> ゆんゆん「しょ、紹介します。こちらはただの駆け出し冒険者の男の子とアークプリーストの女の子。今はいないけど他にやたら頑丈なお姉さんもいるんですよ。

It should be parsed like this:

> 他に[やたら頑丈な]お姉さんもいる

where やたら is an adverb meaning "very", "pretty", "darn", etc. and describing a high degree to which the following adjective applies to the modified noun. This seems to be a pretty colloquial usage because although I hear and see it pretty commonly, I can't seem to find a clear dictionary definition. [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%9F%A2%E9%B1%88-648527) may give us a clue: めちゃくちゃ

The sentence in question thus means:

> ゆんゆん「しょ、紹介します。こちらはただの駆け出し冒険者の男の子とアークプリーストの女の子。今はいないけど他にやたら頑丈なお姉さんもいるんですよ。
> ゆんゆん: Le, let me introduce you to some people. This is a mere newbie adventurer, a guy. And this is the archpriest, a girl. There is another **darn strong girl** who is not here at the moment.

Let's see some other examples:

> や、やたら頑丈だぜこのトビラ
> Darn sturdy gates

[image]

> ゲームでやたら強い敵キャラがいて「ああ・・・これ負けイベントか」と思って負けたら普通にゲームオーバーになって驚いたことはありますか？
> When playing a game, have you ever encountered a darn strong enemy that makes you wonder if you are supposed to lose to that character but when you actually lose it's game over?

Answer (score 1):

「他に」の意味は「something else」

「矢鱈」（やたら）の意味は「very much (an adverb)」

そして「ほかにやら」意味は「what's more, there is something　else very very....」

因みに「やたら」と「やったら」は意味が違って気を付けてください。